# Need help in Image Similarity search engine

Tags: computer-vision

I need to build a Jewellery Image Similarity engine.
As in if the user shows an image of a Golden earring with blue stones, the similar jewellery images should be fetched from our DB.

I have a dataset of about 19k images that are totally unlabeled of different jewellery articles like Earrings, Bracelet, etc.

Currently I have categorized them using CLIP model by feeding text like "a photo of earring, bracelet,etc"

As of now I use the 512 dimension embeddings provided for these images Then I use Spotify Annoy library to get ANN for the embeddings.
Which is giving me a decent result.

[image]

As you can see the ANN search fetches earring with blue stones but it fetches both silver and golden.

I think of training a model like resnet18 after labeling the data in stricter classes like "**golden** earring with blue stone", "**silver** earring with blue stone".
And then using the embeddings.

Also I use the standard option of using angular distance with 10 trees option in Spotify Annoy.
Can someone suggest how can I build a better search.

Comment: regarding your problem statement, did you find any approach to it?

Comment: hi I just had to get similar images out of my own dataset. So i had gone for this approach - 
Extract vector from the largest variant of CLIP model
then use library like Annoy or third party vector DB providers like ChromaDB, Weaviate etc
For my Dataset Cosine distance similarity worked out best instead of other distance